# How to get spongy slightly chewy pancakes?

Tags: batter, pancakes, consistency

One of my favorite restaurants makes these amazing pancakes that are wide (12+ inches), pretty thin (1 cm?, fairly spongy/chewy and fried crispy on the outside edges.

I'm wondering what steps one must take in order to create batter that produces a spongy/stretchy product?  When I follow most recipes the pancakes comes out more cake/bread like.

If my description is lacking, the only thing I can compare the consistency to would be the pancake like bread that comes at Ethiopian restaurants, which I believe is called [Injera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injera)

Side note:
These definitely weren't crepes though they were sort of shaped like them.  They didn't have the "eggy-ness" of crepes.

Comment: It might help to provide an example recipe you use that often turns out too cakey or bread-like. Then folks could offer tweaks.

Comment: You might want to look at ‘Dutch baby’ recipes.  They’re unleavened, so they’re not what many people would consider to be a pancake, but they can be a bit chewy depending on how they’re cooked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my reading, injera is a sourdough-leavened flatbread, and it does indeed have the consistency you describe. I've made it with wheat and (the more traditional) [teff](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragrostis_tef) flour. It's not sweet or quick-bread (in any sense!) but is fun, tasty, and worth a try to eat or make.

If I'm understanding correctly, what you're looking for is a pancake with qualities I'm often trying to avoid. :) Guesses on how to get where you want, based on what you've got so far, based on what I've done accidentally in the past. Apologies that this is all over the map.

- Over-mix your batter. With quick-breads you often want delicate crumb; over-mixing will give you more gluten development (assuming wheat or other gluten-containing flour). This will have a more rubbery mouthfeel.
- Let your batter rest longer. This will also allow gluten to develop (and/or relax), which might have a similar effect.
- Use a harder (higher-percentage gluten) [wheat flour](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_flour). Flours will vary greatly in protein; try a high protein "bread flour" made with hard wheat.

These might help with the sponginess factor also.

Might also want to experiment with type and amount of leavening.

- more or less quantity of baking powder, or perhaps baking soda optionally with some kind of acid (e.g., buttermilk).
- yeasted pancakes! I can't immediately find a passable recipe link, but James Beard had a lovely (albeit a bit finicky) overnight yeast pancake recipe. Give it about 4 attempts before you abandon it. :)

Wackier suggestions:

- Try soy milk. Unlikely to be how your favorite restaurant is accomplishing it's feat, but this might do something different because of protein or perhaps if there's other adulterants or thickeners like gums or so.
- Go off the deep end: try a thickener like corn starch, arrowroot, carrageenan, xanthan gum, ...
- Try a gluten-free pancake recipe or mix. Who knows!

Good luck! Have fun! And let me know if I've missed your goal.

Comment: Do we know which method the OP used in order to select this answer?

Answer (score 3):

I know what you mean...most commercial pancakes are spongy and I love them.

For approx. 2 cups of flour or pancake mix, add a nice handful (1/4 cup) of farina (fine cream of wheat) to the liquid and warm a little to soften.  I also let the batter sit.  Works pretty well in my griddle.

Answer (score 1):

This thread has a good discussion of ingredient changes and I'll defer to other posters there. But might technique also play a large part in the desired texture?

I recently attended a conference and the hotel's banquet-hall breakfast served pancakes. They obviously had been cooked in large volumes and stored covered in the chafing dish prior to service. This makes sense for volume operations. The pancakes were exactly as OP described. And I also recently heated up some home-made leftover pancakes. As an experiment, I ran them under the sink quickly to provide some extra moisture, then heated them on the griddle as normal. The "original" batch was just a normal pancake but the wetted-reheated pancake was much closer to OP's description. So perhaps a "steamed" pancake is one way to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You need sour dough pancakes. This requires a sour dough START. If you don't have a start you're screwed. If you have a start, feed it the night before with 2 cups flour, 2 cups water and 1 TBS sugar. Leave out lightly covered and see the magic in the morning.
Next morning reserve 1 cup of start and to the rest add:
2 tsp salt
2 tsp sugar
2 tsp baking soda
3 eggs

Comment: Nope. You can make the described pancake perfectly well with yeast, flour and water. While you can make a sourdough version, it's not remotely required.

Answer (score 0):

The wonderment you are seeking is typically achieved in vegan pancakes.

First and foremost, you will need a secondary flour that will allow the "spongy" effect you desire as wheat flour or all purpose flour is not enough and the gluten development will only make the pancakes "tougher" or more dense.

White Rice Flour (ie Bob's Red Mill) is a perfect option.

Use a ration of 4 to 1 or if you use a 1 cup of flour, use .25 cup of white rice flour.

Use soy milk and for every cup use a tablespoon of vinegar to allow for curdling.
And if you have soy or sunflower lecithin, use a .25 teaspoon as an emulsifier and binder. If not, needn't worry it is strictly optional.

Do not use hot water as that will cook the rice flour and ruin the batter.

I have successfully done precisely what you seek time and again.

Comment: Here is Dupar's copycat recipe:

Answer (score -1):

You’re describing the pancakes at DuPar’s in Los Angeles!

I suspect the batter is beaten longer than usual, and let to sit (I have noticed that at peak breakfast/brunch times they are slightly less chewy).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/83661)

Comment: Here is Dupar's copycat recipe:    https://gotogittle.com/dupars-pancake-copycat-recipe/   The beaten eggwhite is the big difference.